# shorthand C while loop

Tags: c, optimization, while-loop

Quick one. Are the following equivalent? And are any of them more economical or "correct" than the others?

`while (x==y) {}`, `while (x==y) ;` & `while (x==y);`.

Note the white space between the closing expression bracket and the semicolon in the second one and not in the third.

I have tended to use the first one in the past.
Ta

Comment: What are they supposed to do? There are better ways to spin wait.

Comment: @SLaks just wait until the condition is un-true, but no specific use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference between the second and third one.

The only difference for the first is readability - you're explicitly stating you want an infinite loop, not that you have a typo (extra `;`).

Answer (score 2):

They're all exactly equivalent and should produce identical programs with any half-sane compiler. The whitespace is not significant and both `{}` and `;` represent the empty statement.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you'd doing something like this, you still put the semicolon on its own line to make it clear that it wasn't just added by acident:

```
while (whatever)
    ;
```

Of course, you usually only do that when `whatever` has side-effects, such as:

```
// skip to end of line:
while (((ch=getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
    ;
```

The exact syntactic form of empty statement you use is extremely unlikely to affect the code produced though, so this is purely about optimizing for the reader, not the compiler.

Comment: @Toby: ...or, `x` (or both, of course) -- that's why I said "usually".  While `volatile` is surely possible, it's not all that common, and when you are dealing one, you don't usually want to do it in a spin loop like this.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Why would you not want to use a spin loop for volatile polling?

Comment: @Toby: because most of the time the OS will provide something that provides the same effect, but lets something else use the CPU while you're waiting. The primary exception is if you're sure the wait will be much shorter than switching to some other task then switching back.

Comment: Ah OK, that's what I get for generalising my use case... I have no OS! and in this specific case, yes, the wait _should_ be very short, in fact the while{} is used just to ensure that for the exception where the wait is any longer than the operation time for a couple instr executions then we wait for the hardware to catch up. Thanks again.

Comment: @Toby: Even when you have no OS, unless you're doing only single tasking, you'll normally build something like this into your task switcher. But yes, for *really* short operations, a spin loop is perfectly reasonable (though I'd also note that optimizing an idle loop is pretty much the classic example of useless optimization).